# MySQL SELECT MAX datetime and information related to it

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the last time and location that a user has logged in. I have 2 tables, a Users table and User_Logins table.

### Users Table

```
id    INT
fname VARCHAR
lname VARCHAR
team  VARCHAR
```

### User_Logins Table

```
id        INT
user_id   VARCHAR
location  VARCHAR
date_time DATETIME
```

### Query

```
SELECT u.id, u.fname, u.lname, ul.location, MAX(ul.time_accessed) AS last_login_time
FROM Users AS u 
  INNER JOIN User_Logins AS ul
    ON u.id = ul.user_id
WHERE team = 'TEST-TEAM-1'
GROUP BY u.id
```

Now this works as far as getting the last login time for each user on the team, but it doesn't give me the correct location. How would I go about getting both the last_login_time and login location?

Thanks!

Comment: you'd have to do it in two stages. one query to get the per-user max time, then use those results to fetch the overall record(s) that have those userid/datetime pairs in it. it can't be done with a single select, because the max() results won't be available at the time the rest of the rows are being considered.

Comment: You query complies only because `MySQL` enables its [`GROUP BY` extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a subquery and get the maximum accessed value per each user id and then join again with users table to get details.

```
SELECT * FROM
Users U
JOIN 
(SELECT u.id, MAX(ul.time_accessed) AS last_login_time
FROM Users AS u 
  INNER JOIN User_Logins AS ul
    ON u.id = ul.user_id
WHERE team = 'TEST-TEAM-1'
GROUP BY u.id ) T
on U.id = T.id
JOIN User_Logins ul
on ul.user_id = T.id
and ul.time_accessed = T.last_login_time
```

Comment: At first I didn't quite grasp what was going on in the above query, but it's all good now. Thank you Rajesh! This works wonderfully!